# Does MySQL generate indices for UNIQUE and FOREIGN KEY constraints implicitly or should I actually create them explicitly?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance

Let's consider a database of 2 simple tables: `tablea` has an INT `id`, a VARCHAR `something` field and references `tableb` (containing a same field but with UNIQUE constraint added).

MySQL Workbench will generate the following code if we use it to design and forward-engineer this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tableb` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `something` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `something_UNIQUE` (`something` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tablea` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `something` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `tableb_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `tableb_id`),
  INDEX `fk_tablea_tableb_idx` (`tableb_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tablea_tableb`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tableb_id`)
    REFERENCES `tableb` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

but we can seemingly reach the same effect (same schema of tables, columns and constraints) with more simple, minimalistic code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tableb` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `something` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE (`something`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tablea` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `something` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `tableb_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `tableb_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`tableb_id`) REFERENCES `tableb`(`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Is the first version any way better (e.g. faster) than the second? Won't MySQL create the indices mentioned in the first version in the second case as well?

Comment: Why do you think that MySQL would automatically index a column?

Comment: for FK's sure in the *referencing* if needed based on left-most. It can be seen after the fact with `show create table myTable` . In the *referenced* no for FK's as the attempt to `ALTER TABLE` or create the child via `CREATE TABLE`will just fail

Comment: You definetely need to define it, as, for example if you want an auto_increment, you have to define it too. MySQL engine is not reading what you think, you need to define all params. Cheers!

Comment: @JoëlBonetRodríguez he is not talking about auto incs and PK's

Comment: i was only clearing this point, you have to define ALL as i said. And the answer of the last question of the post can be answered by himself testing it on a clear enviornment. huh?

Comment: You don't have to define all, it depends what you are doing.

Comment: after all, mysql will return the time it takes to reach the job and then you can inspect the structure and properties to see if indices and many other stuff were created or not. Why to ask this here if you can test it in 5min? :/

Comment: To discuss it. For instance you just learned something: you don't always have to define everything :p

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - UNIQUE and FK constraints _do_ generate indexes.  Sometimes the even avoid generating redundant indexes.

Answer (score 0):

In your last chunk as I mentioned in comments and as the manual says, you do not need to explicitly create the FK-related keys in the child tables (the referencing). MySQL will auto create them for you if needed based on left-most (or first most as the manual says). A single column index is naturally left-most. For composites, that is multi-column keys, left-most naturally makes some sense.

It will be very apparent if you run your above, and issue a

```
show create table tablea;
```

If you happen to have a left-most key defined already in a child, and it is usable for the FK relationship, the engine will not create one for you on its own.

From the manual page entitled [Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

> In the referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
>   columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. Such an
>   index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not
>   exist. This index might be silently dropped later, if you create
>   another index that can be used to enforce the foreign key constraint.
>   index_name, if given, is used as described previously.

Also as I mentioned in the comment section under your question, the *referenced* table (the parent), however, must have the necessary left-most keys in place for fast lookup prior to all of this. That key does not need to be a `PRIMARY` or unique key. But it must be available left-most for composites. If one is not available in the parent prior to the `ALTER TABLE` or `CREATE TABLE` of the child, then the operation fails with

> MySQL Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

As for a few quick examples of when a key is created on your behalf (or not) in child tables:

1. If you explicitly create a key on col1, and it is used in an FK, a helper key is not created for you.
2. If you explicitly create a composite key on (a,b,c,d), and you have an FK on (a,b), then a helper key is not created for you.
3. If you explicitly create a composite key on (a,b,c,d), and you have an FK on (a,c), then a helper key is created for you. Because the `b` gets in the way on the explicit and a new key is required.
4. If you explicitly create a composite key on (a,b,c,d), and you have an FK on (a,b,c), then a helper key is not created for you. The left-most on the explicit, in the same order, was more than adequate for the requirements of the FK.

Comment: So can the first version of the schema (generated by MySQL Workbench) be expected to work faster than the second version (without the `index` keyword used)?

Comment: they are identical for MySQL auto generates `fk_tablea_tableb_idx` if all you type in is the 2nd chunk. Which, as  I said, is visible if you type `show create table tablea`